# is it possible to stub an instance variable in rspec in a non controller test?

Tags: rspec, stub, ivar

I would normally set an instance variable in my controller, but I am unit testing a model method which depends on the value of the instance variable set in the controller.

Using rspec, is it possible to stub or set this instance variable for the test?

Everything I've seen so far makes it seem that I can only stub/set an instance variable from controller or view tests, not model tests.

Comment: The code I'm trying to unit test is:   def sort_special
    if @myvar.present?
      special_sort
else
 regular_sort
    end
  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am unit testing a model method which depends on the value of the instance variable set in the controller.

That's a wrong way to go, [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) dictates that we make a strong boundary between those three components and integrate everything in controllers. If you really must go that way, can you at least show the code in which you're using a controller variable?

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Normally, I would instantiate the instance variable in the controller, but I'm trying to test the method in question outside of the controller unit tests. Is that valid?

Comment: Yes, you test your models with unit tests for models. But what's the purpose for bounding models to controllers?